# Can I use a _FillValue when reading a netCDF file in Julia?

Tags: julia, netcdf

I use the package `NetCDF.jl`.

I have a netCDF file `file.nc` which contains variable `var1`.  In principle, `var1` contains possitive values.  A mask value of `var1` is defined in the netCDF file, namely `_FillValue = -1.e+34`.  However, if I `ncread("file.nc", "var1")`, `var1` presents the _FillValue as `-1.e+34`, while I want this value to be interpreted as `NA`.

Is there a way to use the _FillValue properly, as in that it is set to `NA`?  Is this functionality already available in a different package?

Alternatively, can I make Julia somehow interpret `-1e+34` as `NA`?  In that case, this would work for any numerical data, defined or read in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is an [open issue](https://github.com/JuliaGeo/NetCDF.jl/issues/39) for `NetCDF.jl`.  It refers to another package called `NCDatasets.jl` which does provide this feature.

In short, at least for now, use [NCDatasets.jl](https://github.com/Alexander-Barth/NCDatasets.jl) if you want `_FillValue` support.